# Picking up File with Latest Timestamp Talend

Tags: talend

I have designed a Talend Job which will pick up a file from S3 location. I have written a copy command in tRedshiftRow component.Now the Copy Command looks like below:-

```
truncate Table A;
commit;
copy  Table A 
(
Column1
Column2
Column3
)
from 's3://*/*/*/*_2017-02-17_14-22-48.txt'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=x;aws_secret_access_key=x'  
DATEFORMAT 'YYYYMMDD' TIMEFORMAT 'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS' delimiter '|' IGNOREHEADER 1 IGNOREBLANKLINES ACCEPTINVCHARS ;
```

The Filename everyday will be like `x_2017_MM_DD HH-MM-SS.txt` where x is like File Name.`MM-DD` will change everyday.Can anyone please help me out

Comment: you can use the function : TalendDate.getDate() maybe

Comment: How to do?in the context?

Comment: try this...DATEFORMAT 'YYYYMMDD' TIMEFORMAT 'x_"+TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy", TalendDate.getCurrentDate())+"_"+TalendDate.formatDate("MM", TalendDate.getCurrentDate())+"_+TalendDate.formatDate("dd", TalendDate.getCurrentDate())+"_14-22-48.txt' delimiter '|' IGNOREHEADER 1 IGNOREBLANKLINES ACCEPTINVCHARS"..